# Azure AD Connect password sync - sync runs but no passwords change

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We use a cloud-hosted Office 365 domain for e-mail. Our users are synced from our Server 2008 R2 functional level domain.

Until a fortnight ago we were successfully using DirSync for this synchronisation process. Users and passwords were synced with the cloud and everything worked fine. If a user changed their AD password, the sync would run every 30 minutes and update their e-mail password.

As DirSync is being deprecated, we moved to Azure AD Connect. This has been set up in the same way - pointed at the same OU, password synchronisation enabled.

[image: sync settings]

The synchronisation process appears to run successfully every 30 minutes:

[image: sync running successfully]

When the system detects a password change, I can see this in the miisclient application:

[image: password change update]

The problem is... **the passwords don't appear to be changing**. Everyone who has changed password since we installed Azure AD Connect is still having to use their **old** password to log in to e-mail.

I have tried:

- Forcing a full synchronisation using the command `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial`. The sync runs, and objects are updated, but same issue with passwords still applies
- Running a password synchronisation script (which at its core uses the syntax `$p = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.ConfigurationParameter "Microsoft.Synchronize.SynchronizationPolicy", String, SynchronizationGlobal, $null, $null, $null` as well as a number of other command lines which I won't paste unless required). Not entirely sure what this did, if anything
- Checking event viewer - but no errors at all

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm missing to enable the password synchronisation?

Comment: Is anything syncing?  Your screenshot is missing "Export" which is what would actually propagate the change.  Are you in staging mode perhaps?

Comment: Oh wow... I totally misread how Staging Mode works. Yep, that's the culprit!! Would you like to put an answer in @CtrlDot and I'll award you with the green tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot above, you are missing the "Export" task on both the local AD and the AAD.

This is generally the case when "staging" mode is turned on.

See [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-operations/#staging-mode) for more information.

Try turning off staging mode.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. And for not mocking my stupidity :D